# How to display a button on the picture that sees the change of "screen" in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Please tell me how to put a button on top of the picture (picture below), it should be located in the lower right corner of itself. And this button should lead to another screen (navigationview). Thanks in advance !

[image]

For a long time I tried to figure it out on my own, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take reference from this code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
            ZStack{
                    Button (action: {})
                    {
                        VStack{
                            ZStack{
                                VStack{
                                    Image("image")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .overlay {
                                            Button {
                                               // any action 
                                            } label: {
                                                Text("Let's Get acquainted")
                                                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                    .bold()
                                                    .position(x: 150, y: 100)
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```